# proper structure for query. not getting log output

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to do a simple equalTo() in firebase on some test data I have uploaded. This is the code.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://crackling-fire-1105.firebaseio.com/business");
ref.orderByChild("city").equalTo("Pétion-Ville").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

I am getting nothing in the console.

If i use the firebase doc code next to my own code it works.https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

Index.on errorI am getting. (this has been resolved in comments below)

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "city" at /business to your security rules for better performance

After getting it the first time, I added .indexOn: "city". I am still getting that error and I am getting nothing in the console.

These are the Rules in Security and Rules console.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        ".indexOn": "city"
    }
}
```

The json structure is as follows:

```
{
 business {
     Joe's Designs: { 
                 "accountid"
                 "address"
                 "city"
                 "email"
                 "heading"
                 "headingid"
                 "objectId"
                 "phonenumber1"
                 "website"
                 }

            }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Specify `.indexOn` below the key you need the index for.**

```
{
   "rules": {
     "business": {
        ".indexOn": "\"city\""
     }
   }
}
```

This allows you to have an `.indexOn` rule for any top level key.

From looking at your data, you appear to be escaping the keys. I'm not sure why you're doing this, but this will require you to use the escaped value for indexing and querying.

[**JSBin demo**](http://jsbin.com/binozikihu/edit?js,console)

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://crackling-fire-1105.firebaseio.com/business");
ref.orderByChild("\"city\"").equalTo("Pétion-Ville").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That works. Any idea on why its not logging results to the console? Structure of the code looks right. I am not getting any errors in dev tools. The request is hitting the server hitting and I know there are results there with that city. Nothing is logging in the console though.

Comment: Figured it out. It has to do with how you're storing your keys. Take a look at the answer.

Comment: So that is interesting. I used http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm to convert from CSV to JSON. I noticed the escaping keys(did not know it was called that) but could not find a conversion on that site that did not do it. When i imported to firebase i saw that the keys were not there so I thought i was cool, which it was not. I went back to the original file and saw the prototype object keys and properties where """key""":"""foo""' for some reason. How were you able to see that? Still learning. Thank you.

Comment: I did a REST request by appending .json at the end of your URL. Glad everything is looking better. Can you mark the answer as accepted if there are no other considerations?

Comment: So that worked for you? I took out the 3x quotes, uploaded the data and still nothing.

Comment: It now says there's no data at `/business' but I can see that it's all at root now. But wherever you put the data, my answer should still work. Let me know if there are any other considerations.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I very much appreciate your help there. I will file escaping clauses away for future reference. Is there a way to show appreciation for someone on here besides the check mark? Happy Holidays